# How to add more than one fullcalender in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar

I want to have two fullcalenders in angularjs app. How can I achieve it?

```
<div id="calendar" ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar" ng-model="eventSources" calendar="myCalendar"></div>
<div id="calendar" ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar" ng-model="eventSources" calendar="myCalendar"></div>
```

Comment: not duplicating your IDs would probably help

Comment: i have done it. thank you everyone

Answer (score 0):

You can basically have two similar tag, like:

```
<div id="calendar1" ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar" ng-model="eventSources" calendar="myCalendar1"></div>
<div id="calendar2" ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar" ng-model="eventSources" calendar="myCalendar2"></div>
```

Then, in your controller, you'll have two different variables, to control both different calendars.

Comment: i have different functionalty for both the calender .so i want to handle this . but unable to do this.I want to make both calender to add , edit delete event.and i need selectable . and selectable functionality will be different for both the calender

Comment: I suggest you read and learn more how angularjs and javascript works. Follow this tutorial: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial. It may help a lot.

Comment: i have implemented it but unable to detectr c which calender click is performing. Please have a look her http://flamboyant-franklin-77ac14.bitballoon.com/